# C# / LINQ - having trouble querying database with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database with two entities, A and B. A and B have a many-to-many relationship between them (there's also an AB table too that is created automatically to realize this). A has A_prop (key) and B has B_prop (key).

I want to, given a specific B_prop, find all the A's that have in its relationship of B's, (call them Ayes and Bees for the respective Navigation Properties), the B with the specific B_prop.

So I have this code:

```
public class Repository
{
    private ABEntities entities = new ABEntities();

    public IQueryable<A> FindAllA(string b_prop)
    {
        return from b in entities.Bs
        where b.B_prop == b_prop
        select b.Ayes;
    }
}
```

The return types here doesn't match. What I would really like is to have a List of A's, or something similar that I can work with as in the following manner:

```
List<A> listofa = repository.FindAllA("some string");
foreach (A a in listofa)
{
    // Do my stuff here.
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies. This is a solution (tested) to my problem:

```
public List<A> FindAllA(string b_prop)
{
    return (from b in entities.Bs
            where b.B_prop == b_prop
            select b.Ayes).First().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling `.First` on your initial subset, consider using `SelectMany` to flatten your result set:

```
public List<A> FindAllA(string b_prop) 
{ 
    return (from b in entities.Bs 
            where b.B_prop == b_prop
            from a in b.Ayes
            select a).ToList(); 
}
```

This way if for some reason you had multiple records that matched in your Bs table, all of the associated As would be returned rather than just the first set matching up to your first B result. The problem with your first try is that you were returning `IQueryable<EntitySet<Ayes>>` rather than `IQueryable<Ayes>`. `SelectMany` flattens this relationship out.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Repository {

        private ABEntities entities = new ABEntities();

        public IList<A> FindAllA(string b_prop)
        {
            return (from b in entities.Bs
                   where b.B_prop == b_prop
                   select b.Ayes).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I highly recommend you dont return queryables from a repository since each queryable implementation is different (linq/entities/sql/etc)

Comment: I would return a IEnumerable<A> not IList<A> so that if who every is calling this can choose if they want an Array or a List. :) but that's just me.

Comment: I tried to run your code but I get the following error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Database.A>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Database.A>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: OK, it works if I do ... select b.Ayes.ToList()).First(); since there will only be one b with the given b_prop and those Ayes will be in a list (once casted), and that will be in some EntityCollection but will be the only item in the list.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey ya either or - enumerable or list will both be fine. my implementations choose list because I like lists, but personal choice depending on app/api requirements. the point here is to avoid Iqueryable.

Comment: @pkr298 did you define a separate Database.A class outside of the one generated by the entity framework?

Comment: @AdamTuliper No, that was the only one. But I figured out what the problem was. Selecting a collection (b.Ayes) returns a EntityCollection<A>, but it was selecting multiple collections, so I need just the first one, and convert that to a list. The solution I gave 2 comments up also doesn't work. I will edit my question with what works, and I've tested it.

Comment: Wow guys, I answered first (1 minute before). :D And yet this answer gets the fame! I don't want to complain though :P

Comment: true, all our answers were within a minute of each other - but I provided a bit more detail with a very important point as to why you shouldnt use IQueryable with the repository rather than just saying "tolist"  : )

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey actually.. now that I think about it - theres a distinct reason for the list. The list conversion forces immediate execution, enumerable in EF code will be a deferred execution which can easily lead you into context issues in a web environment when binding data possibly outside the context

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ query usually returns an `iQueryable<type>`. You can convert this to a list by doing:

```
        return (from b in entities.Bs
               where b.B_prop == b_prop
               select b.Ayes).ToList();
```

in your function.

Answer (score 0):

You have one IQueryable and other one is there fore not matching Just return `List<A>` that should work